# How can I take a file string and remove data from the end of it?

Tags: cmd

A bit tricky to explain which is why my Google-Fu is letting me down here, I'm basically trying to write a script that will scan a directory and copy the latest set of backups from it to another location. The backups will have the format something like:

```
backup-001
backup-001-i001
backup-001-i002
backup-001-i003
backup-002
backup-002-i001
backup-002-i002
backup-002-i003
```

etc.

Where backup-001 is the full backup and backup-001-i001 is the first incremental and so on until the next full backup (backup-002) is run.

I have the first part of the script sorted from a post on this site that will find the latest file and copy it:

```
pushd "\\nas\backup\bit-cw backup"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%a
copy "%newest%" C:\test
popd
```

Now I need to find some way of having it find the newest file, which might be for example backup-035-i003 and for it to then copy all files matching backup-035* to the new location, in other words it will copy the latest full backup plus all incrementals for that backup.

I'm thinking I need to somehow take the filename it has determined is the newest and then remove the '-i00x' part, then use that new filename followed by a wildcard in the copy command but I'm hopelessly lost!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
pushd "\\nas\backup\bit-cw backup"
for /f "tokens=2delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%a
copy "*-%newest%*" C:\test
popd
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You already have set the name of newest file into environment variable %newest%. 
Substring of variable content (the first 10 characters from newest filename) can be obtained with **:~** operator, see **SET /?** for help.

```
COPY "\\nas\backup\bit-cw backup\%newest:~0,10%*" "the new location"
```